# European citizen investing in MSCI USA index ETF: to hedge or not to hedge?

Tags: investing, etf, european-union, hedge-funds, long-term

Located in Europe, I am thinking about a long-term (~20 yrs) investment into an ETF that follows MSCI USA Index. I am stuck: should I pick an euro hedged fund or a normal one. My salary is in Euros, my mortgage is in Euros, etc.

To hedge or not to hedge, that is the question. What are pros and cons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the pros are pretty simple: You in effect limit your currency risk and just get exposure to the 'true' return of the index of it's native currency. They also are generally able to hedge much cheaper than you could due to access to wholesale rates etc. Put simply: you lower your short term variance by mitigating the exchange risk.

But, and here comes the key con: hedging is never free, and these ETFs will always have marginally (and sometimes much) higher costs than the un-hedged due to the additional transactions they have to make. Not only that, but historically a lot of currencies just swing against each other and the moves basically cancel each other out over time, so long horizon investors should usually care more about these additional fees than the additional variance the un-hedged version forces them to suck up, as they add up to a lot more cost in the long run than the hedging gives back.

Comment: Thanks. I am having hard time understanding the ETF cost. [un-hedged](https://etf.dws.com/en-gb/IE00BJ0KDR00-msci-usa-ucits-etf-1c-/) vs [hedged](https://etf.dws.com/en-gb/IE00BG04M077-msci-usa-ucits-etf-2c---eur-hedged-/). Are you able to untangle the cost of those two ETFs?

Comment: So the Total Expense Ratio (TER) of the first ETF (the un-hedged) is 0.07%. The TER of the second (hedged) is 0.12%..

Comment: Here it is: [Calculating the ETF cost](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/103949/calculating-the-etf-cost)

Comment: Also, if using Cost Averaging (usually called Dollar Cost Averaging, but which currency is totally beside the point, which is that the monetary rate of investment is held constant and the number of shares purchased varies with volatility) then volatility actually enhances returns.

Comment: @Philip One thing I still don't understand: how can "currencies swing against each other and cancel each other out over time"? Isn't the only important moment the one when I cash out? That's when I would convert from USD to EUR.

Comment: @Danijel unlike stock markets, which have a positive expectation, currencies just tend to shift back and fourth like a neutral random walk, so although you can get hit (in either direction) by the swings when you come to cash out it's generally a small consideration vs the long scale growth of your stock compounding up at a faster rate with the lower fee.

Comment: Thanks. Let's say EUR is 10% weaker against the USD at the moment I want to cash out than it was at the moment I entered my position. Does "currencies swing and cancel each other over time" have any effect at this point? Wouldn't my possitino be 10% stronger if EUR vs USD stayed the same?

Comment: @Danijel yes it would be 10% stronger if EUR vs USD had stayed the same. If this number is greater than the additional money you saved from the lower fees then you would have been better off buying the hedged ETF. In expected value terms its basically just as likely for you to finish 10% better off when the currencies swing the other way, which is why many would argue it to be neutral.

Comment: @Philip OK, I think it's clear now. The fact that currencies usualy swing around each other doesn't really help. It's all about the moment when you acquire a possition and when you exit the possition. What happens in between those two moments doesn't count.

Answer (score 2):

I like the un-hedged dollar-based investment because it diversifies the euro home-currency position.

Answer (score 1):

I'd invest into funds denominated in other currencies (like Nikkei225 in YEN, FTSE100 in GBP). With this approach you will diversify your investment and currency exposure at the same time. No one would hedge a 20 year currency exposure as it was mentioned previously.During such a big time horizon it is even possible that you will obtain liabilities in USD, YEN or GBP thus effectively cancelling out some of your currency risk.