# Calculating the ETF cost?

Tags: investing, etf, fees, hedge-funds

Let's say I invest 1000 USD in an ETF. 
Over the 10 year period, the shares had 5% annualized gain, meaning the value of my investment would be 1630 USD. However, I didn't take into account ETF fees.

What would be the value of my investment in the following cases:

1. ETF cost is 0.05 % (un-hedged)?
2. ETF cost is 0.10 % (hedged)?

I am trying to see how much would hedging cost me over this period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this [Calculator](https://www.thecalculatorsite.com/finance/calculators/compoundinterestcalculator.php) and setting up 3 cases:

```
1. annualized interest rate = 5% 
2. annualizud interest rate = 5% - 0.05%
3. annualizud interest rate = 5% - 0.10%
```

The results are (balance):

```
1. $1,628.89
2. $1,621.15
3. $1,613.45
```

Earnings $:

```
2. My gain is $621 and ETF earned $7. 
3. My gain is $613 and ETF earned $15.
```

Earnings %:

```
2. Me: 98.77% ETF: 1.23%
3. Me: 97.54% ETF: 2.46%
```

In this particular case:

```
ETF 0.05% cost translates to 1.23% of earnings.   
ETF 0.10% cost translates to 2.45% of earnings.
```

It is important to say that the percentage of earning ETF takes:

- doesn't depend on the amount invested
- increases with the investment time
- decreases with the gain your investment had

Answer (score 1):

Using a tool like https://www.thecalculatorsite.com/finance/calculators/compoundinterestcalculator.php you just compare the values of the expected annualized rate minus the relevant basis point cost in each case and see what the difference is between the two.

Comment: Thanks. Could you recheck the calculation in my answer: does it make sense?

Comment: Yes looks correct.